How to calculate the limit of the sets as the half-spaces
In the pp.83 of the book

Khan A A, Tammer C, Zalinescu C. Set-valued optimization[M]. Springer-Verlag Berlin An, 2016.

the definition of limit infimum of set sequence is
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = \{y\in \mathbb{R}^m: \exists y_n \rightarrow y~\text{such that}~y_n\in A_n~\text{for}~n\geq n_0,n_0 \in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
Given a vector sequence $w_n \rightarrow w, w_n,w \in \mathbb{R}^m,w_n \neq 0, w\neq 0$, the set sequence is defined as $A_n =\{v\in \mathbb{R}^m: w_n^\top v \geq 0\}$, which are half-spaces, how to calculate the set limit $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n,$$
I guess that it is $A =\{v: w^\top v \geq 0\}$, however I have no idea to prove it.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What does $\liminf$ mean for subspaces?The limit of those half spaces will be what you guess it is for any reasonable definition of that limit.

If the definition of the liminf is taken as $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k$, then it will not always be $A$. Take $w_n = (1,-\frac 1n)$ and $w = (1,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$. $v = (0, 1)\in A$ and yet $v\notin \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n$. However it is a certainty that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n\subseteq A$ by continuity of the inner product.
Edit: to reflect the definition given:
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = \{y\in \mathbb{R}^m: \exists y_n \rightarrow y~\text{such that}~y_n\in A_n~\text{for}~n\geq n_0,n_0 \in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
Let us show that with this definition, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = A$. For $x = (x_1,\dots,x_m)\in \mathbb R^m$, we recall its $1$-norm: $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^m|x_i|$, which induces the usual topology on $\mathbb R^m$ (all norms are equivalent in finite dimension).
First, suppose $v\in \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$, providing us with a sequence $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ that converges to $v$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0, v_n\in A_n$ for some $n_0\in \mathbb N$. then $w_n^\top v_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq n_0$. By continuity of the inner product on $\mathbb R^m$, we prolong the inequality to get $w^\top v \geq 0$, meaning $v\in A$.
Reciprocally suppose $v\in A$, meaning $w^\top v\geq 0$. Since the sequence $(\|w_k\|_1)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $\|w\|_1\neq 0$, there exists $k_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall k\geq k_0$, $\|w_k\|_1 \geq \frac{\|w\|_1}{2}$. This allows us to set $$M := \min\left(\frac{\|w\|_1}{2}, \|w_1\|_1,\dots,\|w_{k_0-1}\|_1\right) > 0.$$
We now set a fixed value of $k\in \mathbb N$. Writing $w_k = (w_k^{(1)},\dots,w_k^{(m)})$, we set $\forall i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$, $\alpha_k^{(i)} := sign(w_k^{(i)})$ the sign of each coefficient and $\alpha_k := (\alpha_k^{(1)},\dots,\alpha_k^{(m)})\in \mathbb R^m$. Now we set $v_k := v - \frac 1M\min(0,w_k^\top v)\alpha_k\in \mathbb R^m$.
Since $\forall k\in \mathbb N$, $\|\alpha_k\|_1\leq m$ and $\min(0,w_k^\top v)\xrightarrow{k\to \infty}0$, we deduce that $v_k \xrightarrow{k\to \infty}v$. Moreover, let $k\in \mathbb N$:

If $w_k^\top v\geq 0$, then $w_k^\top v_k = w_k^\top v \geq 0$.

If $w_k^\top v < 0$, then $w_k^\top v_k = w_k^\top v\left(1-\frac{w_k^\top \alpha_k}{M}\right) = w_k^\top v\left(1-\frac{\|w_k\|_1}{M}\right)\geq 0.$


Thus $w_k^\top v_k \geq 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$, which implies that $v\in \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$.
Conclusion : $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = A$.

Please see the new edition of my question, which added the definition of limit infimum of set sequence quoted from Khan A A, Set-valued optimization. For this definition, we can choose $v_n =(\frac{2}{n},1) \rightarrow v$ and $v_n \in A_n$, in this sense, by definition, $v \in \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n$.

@RenDejin my answer has been edited accordingly.
